# Netpune: drop large number of vertices getting timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using the following query to drop around 100K vertices inside Neptune.

```
g.V().hasLabel('my-label').drop().iterate()
```

But getting the following error

```
  "errorMessage": "500: {\"code\":\"TimeLimitExceededException\",\"detailedMessage\":\"A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation.\"}",
  "errorType": "GremlinServerError",
```

We can't change the `neptune_query_timeout` at the moment, is there any way I can delete by doing something using `limit`, `count`, or `range` inside the query?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the timeout would be an easy way to let the query complete but given you are not able to change that, an approach using `range` or `limit` can help. Dropping 100K vertices does not usually take very long, so I am assuming those 100K vertices have a lot of edges connected to them.

If you wanted to get even more sophisticated you could look at a multi threaded approach where each thread is given a range of vertex IDs to drop.

Keeping things simple, something like this should suffice at this scale:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('my-label').limit(5000).drop().iterate()
```

Then just repeat the query as many times as needed to get to 100K deletions. Keep in mind that the size of `limit` may need to be adjusted depending on how many edges also need deleting. Whenever you `drop` a vertex, all edges connected to it are also deleted.